# How can i do a process when some clicks on Android menu button - Using a sencha touch2 app

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch 2 based mobile app. I want to show a menu when users clicks on the menu button of android device.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wrapping your application with phonegap/cordova, see the [Cordova API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton).

If you are not see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790860/how-to-handle-device-back-button-on-sencha-touch-application).

Good Luck,

Brad

Comment: I am not using phonegap.... The second link only talk about back handling which is actually a default back handling.

Comment: Yup sorry, I misread that. Only way I know how is with PhoneGap.

Comment: Sencha Touch does not yet support the Android back button, you will need to use PhoneGap/Cordova or something similar for now.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch does not support the Menu or Back buttons on Android, without wrapping the app using Cordova (or something like it).  The functionality simply is not possible at this time with Sencha Touch alone.

Once you have Cordova ready for use in your ST app, you can listen for the menu button using this:

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", function() {
    //do your menu functionality here
}, false);
```