# android back button with sencha touch v2

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am new to developing a sencha touch application. I am converting this application for android. I am trying to use the back button of the android device in my app, but I could not get the proper result. Below are the relevant parts of the app.js file.

```
launch:function(){
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Myapp.view.Main'));
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();  
        alert('the back key is pressed');  
    }, false);  
},
```

The above code is just for checking if the callback for pressing the back button of the android device is called or not. But unfortunately I can't see the alert message.
Is there any kind of improvement I can apply to the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You must use phonegap with sencha after that you can listen back button. Look this site http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Comment: i have already reading this page and previously trying that code, but it could not work for me.

Comment: i have read from the following page [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790860/how-to-handle-device-back-button-on-sencha-touch-application).

Comment: use must insert phonegap script into the index.html file. First load this after that listen the deviceready event.
Listen for onload event of the index.html file and write this code inside it 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
After that write a method 
function onDeviceReady(){ document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('the back key is pressed');
}, false)} 
Because you must first initialize the phonegap script. When the script loaded succesfully it fires deviceready event. After this event you can listen back button

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the purpose of using `Ext.bind` to accomplish that.
Change your code to:

```
launch:function(){
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Myapp.view.Main'));
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", Myapp.app.backKeyDown, false);
    alert("after eventlistener");
},

backKeyDown: function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('the back key is pressed');
},
```

and it should work.

[EDIT]:

Since you are saying it's still not working, my guess is that you could have scope problems with your callback:

Try:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('the back key is pressed');
}, false);
```

Comment: i am read from this page [android back button working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790860/how-to-handle-device-back-button-on-sencha-touch-application).  Then i implementing these code in my application.

Comment: I am also trying your suggetion code in my app.js file, but unfortunately this solution could not work for me.  only see the alert('after eventlistener') message.

Comment: @Nayan_Dabhi No permissions required. If that is not working try to call your callback statically like: `Myapp.app.backKeyDown` or put a function there directly `function(){ e.preventDefault(); alert('the back key is pressed'); }`. See my edit to the post.

Comment: @Aubis  Not getting an alert message. I have no idea to where is my mistake or any kind of faults.

Comment: Are you looking at the console? Are there any errors? Where are you testing this?

Comment: i am converting the sencha touch application into apk file using phonegap, Then check on directly on device.

Comment: if you have any link or example for these then please give for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement back button functionality of android using cordova.
In your index.html write the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("In device");
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
 function onBackKeyDown() {
        alert("hello");
    }

    </script>
```